# Can DML triggers be useful in alerting?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I've often thought of how triggers can be useful but have not created any.

I have a business need to trigger an alert email when an elective-type patient expires.  This rarely happens, so it seems resource intensive to have an SSRS or SSIS function check every hour for something that may only happen once per year.

So, I started thinking about DML triggers with AFTER type.  When the Discharge Disposition = 'Expired' and Admit Source = 'Elective', then send an alarm email or some other notification to specified users.

Is this a good use of Triggers or am I putting a burden on the database that would be better served elsewhere?  Has anyone been successful and happy with DML triggers for business use cases?

Answer (score 0):

Yes generating events is a reasonable use for a trigger.  Note that you shouldn't actually do anything in a trigger beyond inserting a row into a table that holds the notification, or perhaps a Service Broker queue.  Then a background process would actually act on the event.

For email [Database Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/database-mail?view=sql-server-2017) does this for you, and you would just call [sp_send_dbmail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to generate an outgoing SMTP email and queue it to be sent.  Or just write a row to a table you create, and have a background job or application read it and send mails, or trigger whatever downstream process you need.